# How to select all duplicate rows except original one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHARACTER VARYING
);
```

with data

```
id    name
-------------
1     John
2     John
3     John
4     Jane
5     Jane
6     Jane
```

I need to select all duplicate rows by `name` except the original one. So in this case I need the result to be this:

```
id    name
-------------
2     John
3     John
5     Jane
6     Jane
```

How do I do that in Postgresql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) to identify the 'original' records and filter them out.  Here is a method using a [cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html):

```
with Nums AS (SELECT id, 
                     name, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ID ASC) RN
              FROM names)

SELECT *
FROM Nums
WHERE RN <> 1 --Filter out rows numbered 1, 'originals'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from names where not id in (select min(id) from names
group by name)
```